# Installation speed using USB thumb drives

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive

On the command line, I [***cp***'d the debian 11.7 install image](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.en.html#usb-copy-isohybrid), which is a large 3.7GB isohybrid file, from my desktop SSD, to each of two different ~8 year old 8GB thumb drives (memory sticks), neither of which has more than a few hours of minimal use.  Using ***date***s, the two copy times were 8'45" and 10'50".

As install-drives, will the 10'50" drive be ~25% slower for installs?

Comment: Your intuition about relative drive speeds is sound, but the will be moderated by the need for the machines to run install scripts, which will be off of the USB at that point, and so running on the regular hardware.

Comment: @Hack_Saw thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize the scripts would be executed using copies on the internal drive.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the two sticks the same USB version (2.0, 3.0, 3.1, etc.) and do the systems that you're installing on support those USB versions in hardware?

Comment: If it took that long are these USB2 flash drives? Or using USB2 ports? Years ago I found a USB3 flash drive was a bit faster even in USB2 ports, but stopped using USB2 flash drives. Lately found external SSD on USB3  so fast, almost as fast as internal SSD, I find that worth the extra cost. Smaller SSDs similar in size to most flash drives are not all that expensive anymore. Even NVMe drives have dropped a lot in price, but you need USB-C to take advantage of faster NVMe drive.

Comment: @oldfred - i haven't inventoried, but everything is USB2.0 as far as I know

Comment: How old is system. If it has USB3 ports, at least use USB3 flash drives. Some flash drives are also faster than others, but last time I use USB3 flash drive I think it was about 45 min. to write. Read is faster. My install to SSD is very fast and full install from SSD (with toram parameter, so all in RAM)  to NVMe drive was less than 12 min.

Comment: [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre) and links from it may be helpful.

Comment: [ubuntu Installation from USB Stick : Notes about speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre#Notes_about_speed)

Answer (score 1):

> Using dates, the two copy times were 8'45" and 10'50". As install-drives, will the 10'50" drive be ~25% slower for installs?

It's impossible to predict. It depends on many factors.

There isn't always a direct correlation between **read** and **write** speeds, i.e., a slower drive when writing can be equally faster or even faster when reading than the other one. And, of course, the observed differences may have been influenced by other factors during the process. The average of several similar operations (3 or more) will be a lot more accurate than the single sample you have.

When booting the installer or live session what matters is the read speed and the computer where it's running as a whole. After most of it is loaded to RAM the flash drive's performance is irrelevant.

In conclusion, **everything in this question is moot**. Although we can make an educated guess that perhaps the slower drive being written will also be slower when being read that might not be the case. It needs proper testing under controlled conditions.